# c++ segmentation fault in the line with virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

i get segmentation fault and gdb tells me this

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000418710 in IStatus::IStatus (this=0x6f2850, __vtt_parm=0x0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at DisplayWidgets/../SignalContainers/IStatus.hpp:13
13  class IStatus : public virtual IProcessable
```

When i do

```
int signalStrength = 0;
GsmSignalContainer* SignalContainer = new GsmSignalContainer(signalStrength, radioIntegratorComm::GsmLineStatus::GLS_Idle);
```

Can someone tell me what is going on? I can't inherit virtually two times in a row or what?

Top of the hierarchy

```
 * IProcessable.hpp
 *
 *  Created on: Oct 08, 2015
 *      Author: patrykw
 */

#ifndef IPROCESSABLE_HPP_
#define IPROCESSABLE_HPP_

struct IProcessable
{
    virtual ~IProcessable() {};
};

#endif /* IPROCESSABLE_HPP_ */
```

Middle, removing   : public virtual IProcessable makes it compile just fine, adding constructors doesn't change anything, it just moves the error to the line with the constructor.

```
/*
 * IStatus.hpp
 *
 *  Created on: Sep 22, 2015
 *      Author: patrykw
 */

#ifndef ISTATUS_HPP_
#define ISTATUS_HPP_

#include <displayController/SignalProcessor/IProcessable.hpp>

class IStatus : public virtual IProcessable
{
public:
    virtual ~IStatus() {}
};

#endif /* ISTATUS_HPP_ */
```

here is the concrete class with its interface

```
#ifndef GSMSIGNALCONTAINER_HPP_
#define GSMSIGNALCONTAINER_HPP_

#include "../../src_proto/RadioIntegrator.pb.h"
#include "IStatus.hpp"

class IGsmSignalContainer : public virtual IStatus
{
public:
    virtual radioIntegratorComm::GsmLineStatus LineStatus() const = 0;
    virtual int SignalStrength() const = 0;
};

class GsmSignalContainer : public virtual IGsmSignalContainer {
public:
    GsmSignalContainer(int signalStrength, radioIntegratorComm::GsmLineStatus lineStatus);

protected:
    radioIntegratorComm::GsmLineStatus _gsmLineStatus;
    int _signalStrength;

    //IGsmSignalContainer implementation
    radioIntegratorComm::GsmLineStatus LineStatus() const { return _gsmLineStatus; };
    int SignalStrength() const { return _signalStrength; } ;
};

#endif /* GSMSIGNALCONTAINER_HPP_ */
```

and implementation

```
GsmSignalContainer::GsmSignalContainer(int signalStrength, radioIntegratorComm::GsmLineStatus lineStatus)
{
    _signalStrength = signalStrength;
    _gsmLineStatus = lineStatus;
}
```

Comment: I tried to test your code for the problem by removing radioIntegrator related code (since RadioIntegrator.pb.h file content is not shared).  It works fine.